# Rails 3.1 - paperclip and how to display uploaded file

Tags: ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I upload my files (PDF files) to this directory:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/my_addr/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:url => "/my_addr/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

How can I display the uploaded files?

I tried things like:

```
<%= link_to @data.data_file_name, '/my_addr/'+@data.user_id.to_s+'/'+@data.data_file_name %>
```

But unfortunately, it's showing  **routing error**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
<%= link_to @data.data_file_name, @data.url %>
```